# Injected CSS into the Shadow root. Yet styles are getting affected

Tags: css, shadow-dom

I'm building a widget and to avoid css conflicts, I moved widget css into the Shadow root. But the parent website css style is affecting widget even then

Noticed error is happening because of this line on the parent website.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}
```

The question, why is the body attribute in parent website affecting the Shadow root css. Isn't the purpose of Shadow root to avoid these sort of conflict?

How can I avoid this sort of problem?

I was trying to avoid !important but is there any other way?

Comment: Please don't post images of code; instead, include the code in the question.

Comment: Hi Sean. I didn't add code, since it was more of a theoretical question and wanted to show CSS is injected properly into the Shadow root. 

Normally, I only share code here.

Comment: Images of code are inaccessible to people using assistive technology.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inheritable `CSS` properties like `font-size`  pierce the shadow DOM boundary by default. If you want to start with a fresh slate, use `all: initial;` to reset inheritable styles to their initial value when they cross the shadow boundary.

Within your shadow root define:

```
<style>
  :host {
     all: initial; /* subsequent properties are reset. */
  }
</style>
```

Or set the `CSS` properties you don't want to be affected

Answer (score 1):

just because you’re using a web component doesn’t mean the styles of it are entirely isolated.

CSS rules of the page always applied to Web components on the page.

At CSS-Tricks is a good article about this topic: https://css-tricks.com/styling-a-web-component/

Comment: Any way to resolve the issue? ! important?

Comment: You can overwrite the css style in you component, but I would not recommend because that's not the idea behind web components. The including page can always change and you can't overwrite anything.